# How to draw vertical line at a selected bar in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Iam trying to use input.time and pick a bar in tradingview chart. I want to draw vertical line at that bar. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2):

To draw a vertical line on the chart provide the **line.new()** function call with equal **x1** and **x2** arguments.

To activate the interactive mouse selection, add the **confirm=true** to the body of the **input.time()** function, see the example below:

```
//@version=5
indicator("vline on input.time", overlay = true)

inputTime = input.time(timestamp("20 Jul 2021 00:00 +0300"), "Date", confirm = true)

if time == inputTime
    line.new(bar_index, close, bar_index, close + 1, xloc.bar_index, extend.both, color.red)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This code works. But is there any way to draw a vertical line in the place where there are no bars? For example Current time is 10am I want to draw a bar at 10pm